# Is it proven that quantum computation is no better at solving NP complete problems than classical computation?

Tags: np-complete, quantum-computing

Is it proven that quantum computation is no better at solving NP complete problems than classical computation or it's just believed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is suspected that NP-complete problems cannot be solved in quantum polynomial time (i.e., that they are not in BQP), but this hasn't been proved. We don't expect a proof in the near future, since this would imply that P is different from NP.

Comment: What about the other way around. If NP-complete is proved to be in BQP, does that say anything about P vs NP?

Comment: [Nothing was known in 2007](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/02/on-np-in-bqp.html), though that was quite some time ago.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna I think it would not say anything on P vs NP as P vs BQP is also unestablished yet.